# Working with SNMP in Delphi

Tags: delphi, snmp

What is the best way to integrate SNMP V2 alerts functionality into an existing Delphi software?

Are there any well known Delphi libraries? Is it easier to integrate SNMP libraries built in some other language?

Thanks!

Comment: TIdSNMP only implements SNMP v1 at this time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you can use the Indy-SNMP (delivered with Delphi) coponents. Here is a small example (console), this returns the sysDescr of the host:

```
    program snmptest;

    {$APPTYPE Console}

    uses
      SysUtils, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdUDPBase, IdUDPClient, IdSNMP;

    var
      Snmp: TIdSNMP;
      Idx: Integer;

    begin
      Snmp := TIdSNMP.Create(nil);
      try
        Snmp.Query.Host := 'Hostname or IP'; //insert your host here...
        Snmp.Query.Community := 'public';
        Snmp.Query.PDUType := PDUGetRequest;
        Snmp.Query.MIBAdd('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0','');

        if Snmp.SendQuery then
        begin
          WriteLn('Replies: ' + IntToStr(Snmp.Reply.ValueCount));
          for Idx := 0 to Snmp.Reply.ValueCount - 1 do
            WriteLn(Snmp.Reply.Value[0]);
        end;
      finally
        Snmp.Free;
      end;
    end.
```

There are more examples, if you google "Delphi SNMP"..

Comment: Tried Googling, but saw many commercial offerings of dubious quality. Thanks for your answer. I believe it will send my friend off in the right direction.

Comment: Here is a "bigger" project, but it is a few years old...: http://snmprg.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I tried it in Delphi 2010 though I had issue as it didn't work. Until I used [this suggestion](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.internet.winsock/200912/0912013011.html) where they recommend to substitute the IdSNMP unit. Though for sysDescr, i.e. the numbers from your example in the MIBAdd it still doesn't return the system description. Any idea why it is so and how to handle SNMP in the best way in Delphi 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Synapse TCP/IP and serial library

http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download

This project is freeware and open source under modified BSD style license!

**Description**

**SNMP client**

Supports SNMPv1 include traps, SNMPv2c and **SNMPv3** include authorization and privacy encryption.

Used RFC: RFC-1157, RFC-1901, RFC-3412, RFC-3414, RFC-3416, RFC-3826

Supported Authorization hashes: MD5, SHA1 Supported Privacy encryptions: DES, 3DES, AES

The library also supports many other protocols